# How does JMeter generate Content-Type = Multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebkitFormBoundaryxxxxxxxxxx

Tags: jmeter

I am working on creating performance test for an application based on Windows authentication.
Test plan is designed as following :

```
Test Plan
   HTTP Cookie Manager
   HTTP Authorization Manager
   Thread Group
       HTTP Request 1
       HTTP Request 2
```

In the HTTP authorization manager section I have provided the base URL, username, password and selected Mechanism as BASIC_DIGEST.
Now assume that HTTP Request 2 is a file upload scenario.
When the steps were recorded then then the file upload scenario had a Content-Type header which has the value - Multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebkitFormBoundaryxxxxxxxxxx.

Now when I execute the script boundary in the above format is not generated which probably results in script failure. I need to understand what changes I might need to implement in order to generate the Content-Type correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe that you should rather remove Content-Type header from the HTTP Header Manager and tick "Use multipart-form/data" box in the HTTP Request sampler:

   [image]
2. The fact you're getting HTTP Status 401 means that your configuration of HTTP Authorization Manager is not correct. If you're using your Windows domain credentials for accessing the application your "Mechanism" choice might be wrong as Kerberos is way more popular than NTLM so inspect network tab of your browser developer tools and see what are [WWW-Authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) and [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header value, this way you can guess what mechanism is being used exactly and properly configure the HTTP Authorization Manager

More information: [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
I am no longer getting 401 response code. Rather I am getting 200 response code. 
What I have observed now is that the Content-Type that JMeter generates is
similar to 'multipart/form-data; boundary=RCQkexJjLBScxK26S_Rtp513mi4RFrEK4C'
Please note the boundary part. Whereas the Content-Type that Chrome generated
is similar to multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryslyIHy3AHA6pym8K
I am not sure what is supposed to be done so that JMeter generates boundary
having WebKitFormBoundary. I am not sure but I guess this may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure random string is generated for "xxx....." part in Multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebkitFormBoundaryxxxxxxxxxx in header. For example

**Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLyVv5IweFhvAf7wC**

Also make sure, the same string is passed in the body part where you send the data. For example,

POST data:
------WebKitFormBoundary**LyVv5IweFhvAf7wC**
Content-Disposition: form-data; name